# SQLite select rows from today and rows older than today?

Tags: sqlite

How can I select all rows that are older than today?

I've tried:

```
select * from chatHistory WHERE channelID = '%1' AND time >= date('-1 day') order by date(time) ASC;
```

But this only seems to return rows that are 1 day old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For timestamps, `a > b` means that `a` is later/newer than `b`.

"Older" is the opposite.
You want a comparison like `time < date('now')`.